# ¿Cómo puedo convertir de un dataframe a un formato de base de datos?

Tags: python, pandas

tengo este dataframe de ciertas cosas que se requieren en ciertos lugares

```
| Lugar            | Papel Aluminio | Botellas de Plástico | Latas | etc... |
|------------------|----------------|----------------------|-------|--------|
|Pastelería        |            150 |                      |   100 |        |
|Panadería         |             10 |                   10 |    20 |        |
|Licorería         |                |                  100 |       |        |
```

Y así sucesivamente...

Quiero convertirlas al formato de base de datos relacional, para que quede como

```
| Pastelería | Papel Aluminio       | 150 |
| Pastelería | Latas                | 100 |
| Panadería  | Papel Aluminio       |  10 |
| Panadería  | Botellas de Plástico |  10 |
```

¿Cómo se puede hacer con Pandas, para no tener que hacer un ciclo registro por registro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongamos que tu tabla está en el dataframe `df`, puedes usar `melt`, voy a suponer que los nombres de las columnas son tal como las pusiste en la pregunta:

```
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Lugar'], var_name='producto', value_name='Cantidad')
```

Esto va a crear un nuevo dataframe como lo quieres y lo va a asignar a la variable que ya tenías, entonces va a quedar así:

```
Pastelería     Papel Aluminio   150
Pastelería     Latas            100
```

Para eliminar los NaN que te quedan donde no existe relación Lugar/Producto tienes que usar `dropna()`:

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Y listo...

Comment: Si me funciona, muchas gracias pero me regresa ,muchos NaN

Comment: Cierto... puedes usar `df.dropna(inplace=True)` después de hacer el `melt()`